# How can i make a read more button that works to take me to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

`I am building an app using Getx and future and its my first time i want to add a read more button that would show after the text such as "And they will perish..see more" i want this see more that once its clicked to take me to a new page im not able to grasp the logic as im working with future strings that arent initialized yet.

```
this is the future text i want to get  

Obx(() =>Text(homeController.getText())),


class HomeController extends GetxController {
var isLoading = false.obs;
Rx<QuranModel> mod = QuranModel().obs;
final RemoteServices remoteServices = RemoteServices();
RxString ayahText = ''.obs;

@override
void onInit(){
super.onInit();
print('caled init');
fetchData();
}
fetchData() async {
try {
isLoading(true);
final quranModel = await remoteServices.fetchData();
mod.value = quranModel;
ayahText.value = mod.value.data?.text?? 'loading';

} catch (e) {
print('Error while getting data: $e');
// Handle error as needed
} finally {
isLoading(false);
}
}

String getText() {
if (mod.value != null && mod.value.data != null) {
print("called");
return mod.value.data?.text??'loading';
}else {
return 'Ayah data not available';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To go to another screen in Getx just simply without any context:

```
Get.to(() => AnotherScreen());
```